# toggle class when scrolling of page stops/idle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I have this code that if you scroll down it hides the header menu then if you scroll up it displays the header menu again.

What I need is hide the header menu when the scrolling becomes idle e.g. I scroll up header menu displays after 3 second of idle in scrolling it hides the header menu.

```
$(".slides li").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.flex-caption').css({opacity: 1.0});
},
function () {
    $(this).find('.flex-caption').css({opacity: 0.0});
});
$('#nav-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".navmobile").slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 1303) {
            $(".navmobile").hide();
            $("#nav-toggle").removeClass("active");
        }
        else {
            $("#nav-toggle").removeClass("active");
            $(".navmobile").hide();
        }
    });
});
        // Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});
setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 0);
function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.navbar').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    $("#nav-toggle").removeClass("active");
    $(".navmobile").hide();
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
}    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set timeout of 3 seconds to remove some class or do other stuff:

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#myHeader').removeClass('idle-scroll');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Here `clearTimeout` will stop previous timeout and starts new one.